# Is there any way to reduce or increase the probability of a list element being chosen from random choice

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way to reduce or increase the probability of a list element being chosen from a random choice in python.

example:

```
my_list=["apple","banana"]
x=random.choice(my_list)#I want to reduce the chances of banana being picked
```

Comment: how about duplicating it?

Comment: Give an example. You can always assign weights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) instead of `random.choice`. This will allow you to specify weights for each element, but will require you to specify explicitly that you want to draw one element.

```
from random import choices
choices(my_list, weights=probability_weights, k=1)
```

Where `probability_weights` a list corresponding to the probability that each respective element will be selected from `my_list`.